# Inlining require.js text! using Grunt

Tags: javascript, build, requirejs, gruntjs, requirejs-text

I've been experimenting with Grunt and Require JS this afternoon. I'm a big fan of the `text` module and use it to bring in my templates. In non-Grunt based projects I used the `inlineText` and `stubModules` Require JS options to in-line the template files and it works great. However, I'm having trouble getting this to work with Grunt.

**Require Config**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        // Using Bower for dependency management
        text: '../components/requirejs-text/text'
    }
});
```

**Usage**

```
define(['text!template.html'], function (html) {
    // Do stuff with html
});
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
requirejs: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            baseUrl: 'app/scripts',
            optimize: 'none',
            preserveLicenseComments: false,
            useStrict: true,
            wrap: true,
            inlineText: true,
            stubModules: ['text']
        }
    }
}
```

After running `grunt` I get various errors in the console:

- A File Not Found on `/dist/components/requirejs-text/text.js`
- A `Load timeout for modules: text!template.html_unnormalized2`

Two issues then:

- It doesn't seem to be inlining (and then stubbing) the `text.js` code
- It doesn't seem to be inlining the `template.html` file

Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: What does your folder structure look like? Are your sure 'text.js' is in the 'dist' directory when this executes?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. To me, it looks like the build tool is looking for text.js because the word "text" appears in the dependency ['text!template.html']. I'm using the require text plugin too.

Comment: Which require.js lib for grunt are you using, as there are quite a few?

Answer (score 1):

You see the error because you need to indicate to `r.js` where is the `text` module.

You can do that by adding a paths configuration:

```
requirejs: {
    dist: {
        options: {
          baseUrl: 'app/scripts',
          optimize: 'none',
          preserveLicenseComments: false,
          useStrict: true,
          wrap: true,
          inlineText: true,
          stubModules: ['text'],
          paths: {
             'text': 'libs/text' // relative to baseUrl
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Then you'll need to download the `text.js` module into the appropriate directory.

But why your `require.config` is not working?

Because the `r.js` needs to evaluate the configuration at some point. You didn't mention in the question where is your `require.config`, but in case that you want to evaluate it you need to indicate where is to `r.js` (see https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L35):

```
requirejs: {
    dist: {
        options: {
          baseUrl: 'app/scripts',
          optimize: 'none',
          preserveLicenseComments: false,
          useStrict: true,
          wrap: true,
          inlineText: true,
          stubModules: ['text'],
          mainConfigFile: '../config.js' // here is your require.config

          // Optionally you can use paths to override the configuration
          paths: {
             'text': 'libs/text' // relative to baseUrl
          }
       }
    }
}
```